# Setting expiry of CSS files

Tags: css, wordpress, browser-cache, cache-control

I used this google tool to analyze my site. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

The results of this tell me the following:

```
**Leverage browser caching**
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXw3 (15 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js (20 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/…onfig/1510218389239357?v=2.8.17&r=stable (20 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/…config/253358141816050?v=2.8.17&r=stable (20 minutes)
https://bat.bing.com/bat.js (30 minutes)
https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/linkid.js (60 minutes)
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js (60 minutes)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

I am using Wordpress. Where/how do i set the expiration?

Comment: Don't try you cannot ... these are external tools, it's not on your website ... they are related to FB code and Google TM and Analytics and you can do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short Answer*: You can't modify the cache settings on these particular scripts.

*Longer Answer*: There are a few plugins like [WP Hummingbird](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wp-hummingbird/) or [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) that can help you with browser cache settings, as well as the [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) hook.

**However**, with that said, note the URLs on these files. These are on GTM, Facebook, Bing, and a few Google sites. You can't control the expiration on these, as they're being loaded in remotely from external tools with your tracking/analytics scripts or iframes.

These results are ones you'll have to live with, as it's not worth hosting them yourself and modifying the tracking codes just to adjust the cache expiration on them.